# Python:Printing file content

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a newbie to programming and trying to print contents of a file using the following statements but while trying to print the file contents, the output I get is empty space:-

```
with open('myfile.txt','a+') as myfile:               
   myfile.write("hello once again 2")   
   data=myfile.read()  

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is a wrong parameter to the open function. Try to replace `a+` with `r+`, and `read` with `readlines`

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r+') as myfile:
    myfile.write("hello once again 2")
    data = myfile.readlines() #please notice readlines

print(data)
```

Here is a reason for that.
When you open a file with 'a+' flag it is opened for reading and writing but the stream is position in the end the file. That why you read 'empty', because there is nothing.

I would advice you to work with file in two steps. First write to it, and then read it.

What write and read do - they write the content into the file but it is not going to be there immediately unless you close the file or call the `flush` function explicitly. The flush is going to be called in the end of the 'context manager' which is created by `with open('myfile.txt', 'r+') as myfile`. You can imagine 'context manager' as a wrapper which makes sure that 'flush' is called after you've done writing your code under `with` statement.

Comment: Keep in mind that the meaning of  `a+` is operating-system dependant. Look at `fopen(3)` manual pages for different operating systems. For instance on Linux the stream is positioned on the beginning of the file for reading, while on FreeBSD it is positioned at the end of the file. In both cases, output is always appended at the end.

Answer (score 0):

When you write your content your filepointer is at the end of the file.
To read it from the begining you need to reset your pointer.

do `myfile.seek(0)` before `myfile.read()`

for more details see: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

> `f.tell()` returns an integer giving the file object’s current position
>   in the file, measured in bytes from the beginning of the file. To
>   change the file object’s position, use `f.seek(offset, from_what)`. The
>   position is computed from adding offset to a reference point; the
>   reference point is selected by the from_what argument. A from_what
>   value of 0 measures from the beginning of the file, 1 uses the current
>   file position, and 2 uses the end of the file as the reference point.
>   from_what can be omitted and defaults to 0, using the beginning of the
>   file as the reference point.

Answer (score 0):

Since the behavior of `a+` can vary among operating systems, it is probably best not to use it is you want your code to be portable.

Unless your files are *huge* (is in a significant fraction of available RAM) I would do the following.

Read your whole file into a list of lines.

```
with open('myfile.txt') as myfile:
    mylines = myfile.readlines()
```

You can now manipulate `mylines` as you like. Append, insert, change or delete lines as you wish.

At the end, write it all back.

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as myfile:
    myfile.writelines(mylines)
```

To the best of my knowledge, this should behave the same on all Python platforms.